# How to send a simple message from WinRT Client( .NET 4.5) to Desktop Server(.NET 4.0) using Sockets?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, client-server, windows-runtime

I am trying to make a Chat Client-Server application using C#. The Client will be a simple metro application (WinRT) and the server will be "oldfashioned" desktop application. Can you provide a simple code how to establish connection between the server and the client at first and then how to send a 'hello world' message from the Client to the Server. I am looking for solution for this problem from 3 days. I read almost anything about StreamSockets, TcpClient and sockets, and still cant handle the problem. The limitaions of the different platforms are the biggest problem. WinRT can not use TcpClient objects, and the old desktop applications can not create StreamSockets to receive the data from the server. Thank you in advance.

Comment: See maybe this old question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465517/how-can-a-metro-app-in-windows-8-communicate-with-a-backend-desktop-app-on-the-s

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send data between .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.0 with Sockets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10348745/how-to-send-data-between-net-4-5-and-net-4-0-with-sockets)

Comment: @Rup This old topic is not useful, because I need to use only Sockets.

Comment: @StephenCleary They are similar, but I don't think they are the same themes. Because in the other theme I forget to mention what application I am developing, and what technologies are involved. I think this topic is more specific and better written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is not possible.  microsoft has explicitly blocked communicating from winrt apps to other apps on localhost.